# Enabling users to choose email apps for sending emails

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a Flutter app where users can send emails. Currently, I'm using the `url_launcher` package to trigger the default mail app when a button is clicked. When I click on my button I would like to have the choice of the mail app that I want to use and not open the default one automatically.

Is there a way to implement a feature where, upon clicking a button, a list of available email apps appears, allowing the user to choose which app they want to use for composing the email?

```
Future<void> sendEmail(BuildContext context) async {
    final Uri emailUri = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto',
      path: mailvar,
    );
    if (await canLaunchUrl(emailUri)) {
      await launchUrl(
        emailUri,
      );
    } else {
      if (context.mounted) {
        showSnackBar(
          context: context,
          type: SnackBarType.error
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is entirely logical that you don't get to do that. It is an end-user decision, not an app decision which mail app they use.

Comment: Yep, what you want is not possible. The application that the OS uses to handle `mailto:` links is entirely out of your control.